# Parameter 0 of constructor in Class B required a bean of type Class A that could not be found

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jwt

Am making an API authentication feature with JWT in ***Spring boot rest***, but am facing the following error :

> **Description**:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
>   com.icfer.huxy.icfer.controller.UserController required a bean of type
>   'com.icfer.huxy.icfer.service.ApplicationUserRepository' that could
>   not be found.
>
> **Action**:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.icfer.huxy.icfer.service.ApplicationUserRepository' in your
>   configuration.

Below is what I have implemented regarding `ApplicationUserRepository`, and `UserController` classes.

**ApplicationUserRepository.java**

```
import com.icfer.huxy.icfer.model.ApplicationUser;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


public interface ApplicationUserRepository extends JpaRepository<ApplicationUser, Long> {
    ApplicationUser findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**ApplicationUser.java**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class ApplicationUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
import com.icfer.huxy.icfer.model.ApplicationUser;
import com.icfer.huxy.icfer.service.ApplicationUserRepository;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/users")
public class UserController {

    private ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;


    public UserController(ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository,
                          BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @PostMapping("/sign-up")
    public void signUp(@RequestBody ApplicationUser user) {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        applicationUserRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

**My gradle file de is as below :**

```
dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile("com.auth0:java-jwt:3.4.0")
    runtimeOnly('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Below is the link to my project:
[Github link](https://github.com/huxaiphaer/icfer)

Comment: Rather than dumping isolated code in text, it is way more efficient to share a sample that we can actually run (in your github repo). The source code there is missing the package in which the controller is, where your Spring Boot application is, the component scan configuration (if any). So, in a way, all those details are pretty much useless I am afraid.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll, you are right, but for the purposes of privacy , I can't do that now.

Comment: Maybe let me make a quick small project in this context and I share a github link. @StephaneNicoll

Comment: This is the link @StephaneNicoll, https://github.com/huxaiphaer/icfer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more reason sharing an actual sample is helpful as none of the code you've shared provides the information that we need to help you.

On your `@SpringBootApplication` you have the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class IcferApplication { ... }
```

Because you are excluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration`, no `DataSource` is created. There is no `DataSource` so JPA does not kick in. JPA is not started so your JPA repository is not created.

You could have ran your app in debug mode (i.e. by adding a `-Ddebug` system property):

```
   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.sql.DataSource; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type javax.sql.DataSource (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository' (OnClassCondition)
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.data.jpa.repositories.enabled=true) matched (OnPropertyCondition)
```

Also, please don't use `EnableAutoConfiguration` together with `SpringBootApplication`, there is an `exclude` attribute on the latter as well.

Once I removed the exclude on `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` that error went away.

Comment: Wanted to ask you a question , were you enable to create a user in postman with this url http://localhost:8080/users/sign-up